# Include system dependent binary files in war using Maven

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have to distribute a Java EE application to Windows and Linux. Application has several system dependent files (dll’s and so on) in WEB-INF/bin folder

I’m trying this approach.

The project folder tree is like this:

- project
  -- src
  ---- main
  ---- java
  ------ webapp
  -------- ...
  -------- WEB-INF
  ----------- bin (now an empty folder) 
  -- target

I’ve moved all bin files to:

- project
  -- distrib
  ---- bin
  ------ win
  ------ linux

In a first step I’m trying to configure Maven to copy distrib/bin/win to WEB-INF/bin in target folder

In a second step, when the first works, I’ll add two profiles one for windows and another for linux.

In my pom.xml I’ve put these lines:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>distro-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                  <descriptor>distrib/bin.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And here you have the bin.xml source:

```
    <assembly 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd" >
  <id>webtop10.2_bin</id>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/distrib/bin/win</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/WEB-INF/bin</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
          <include>*.*</include>
      </includes>
      <fileMode>0750</fileMode>
      <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
      <lineEnding>keep</lineEnding>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

When I execute mvn package the build is successful but the files are not copied to WEB-INF/bin folder. The assembly plugin says:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (distro-assembly) @ sibila ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: distrib/bin.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I’m new in Maven so I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to have the binary files copied into the `WEB-INF/bin` folder inside the war then I don't think you should use the `maven-assembly-plugin` at all.

Here is a much easier approach:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>distrib/win</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/bin</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This can be specialized with build profiles so that you pick either windows or linux binaries.

Comment: Thanks this is a perfect solution form my problem. Best regards

Comment: @user1806859 Great. I'll upvote your question if you also upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You said the files you want to copy are in `project/distrib/bin/win`, but your assembly descriptor's fileset is copying from `${project.build.directory}/distrib/bin/win`.  Unless you've changed your project's build directory in your POM, `${project.build.directory}` is `project/target`.  The directory in your assembly's fileset should probably be just `distrib/bin/win`, as I believe that directory is relative to the project base:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>webtop10.2_bin</id>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>distrib/bin/win</directory>

            ...

        </fileset>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```